# Openstack "No hosts found to map to cell, exiting"

Tags: openstack

I am running into problems with Devstack installation. I git cloned a fresh Devstack on my machine. Ran `./stack.sh` once, and hit the following problem.

```
2016-12-09 13:57:35.870 INFO migrate.versioning.api [req-64697264-f3e0-4c8d-9fa1-19d9d3ceb744 None None] 344 -> 345... 
2016-12-09 13:57:36.225 INFO migrate.versioning.api [req-64697264-f3e0-4c8d-9fa1-19d9d3ceb744 None None] done
2016-12-09 13:57:36.226 INFO migrate.versioning.api [req-64697264-f3e0-4c8d-9fa1-19d9d3ceb744 None None] 345 -> 346... 
2016-12-09 13:57:45.436 INFO migrate.versioning.api [req-64697264-f3e0-4c8d-9fa1-19d9d3ceb744 None None] done
2016-12-09 13:57:45.436 INFO migrate.versioning.api [req-64697264-f3e0-4c8d-9fa1-19d9d3ceb744 None None] 346 -> 347... 
2016-12-09 13:57:47.680 INFO migrate.versioning.api [req-64697264-f3e0-4c8d-9fa1-19d9d3ceb744 None None] done
No hosts found to map to cell, exiting.

No hosts found to map to cell, exiting.
+lib/nova:create_cell:1                    exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:487                  local r=1
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:488                  jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:488                  jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:491                  [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:497                  kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:383               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:499                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:500                  echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:501                  generate-subunit 1481266214 5859 fail
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:502                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:505                  /home/annakoppad/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2016-12-09-082802.txt for details
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:511                  exit 1
```

Further, I did `./unstack.sh` to and `./clean.sh` to clean everything. The same error resulted.

So, I tried two more options of using virtual environments using `pyvenv` and `virtualenv`. Both of them gave the same error that is shown below.

```
(mystack) annakoppad@annakoppad:~/Desktop/mystack/devstack$ ./stack.sh 
+ unset GREP_OPTIONS
+ unset LANG
+ unset LANGUAGE
+ LC_ALL=C
+ export LC_ALL
+ umask 022
+ PATH=/home/annakoppad/Desktop/mystack/bin:/home/annakoppad/bin:/home    /annakoppad/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
+++ dirname ./stack.sh
++ cd .
++ pwd
+ TOP_DIR=/home/annakoppad/Desktop/mystack/devstack
+ NOUNSET=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
++ date +%s
+ DEVSTACK_START_TIME=1481289987
+ [[ -r /home/annakoppad/Desktop/mystack/devstack/.stackenv ]]
+ FILES=/home/annakoppad/Desktop/mystack/devstack/files
+ '[' '!' -d /home/annakoppad/Desktop/mystack/devstack/files ']'
+ '[' '!' -d /home/annakoppad/Desktop/mystack/devstack/inc ']'
+ '[' '!' -d /home/annakoppad/Desktop/mystack/devstack/lib ']'
+ [[ '' == \y ]]
+ [[ 1000 -eq 0 ]]
+ [[ -n /home/annakoppad/Desktop/mystack ]]
+ set +o xtrace
You appear to be running under a python virtualenv.
DevStack does not support this, as we may break the
virtualenv you are currently in by modifying 
external system-level components the virtualenv relies on.
We recommend you use a separate virtual-machine if 
you are worried about DevStack taking over your system.
```

Any pointers on how to overcome will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the devstack script is failing on this [line of code](https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack/blob/master/lib/nova#L949).
Which means you want to go to the else branch of code. To do this you need to add enable_service n-cell to your existing local.conf settings.

```
    [[local|localrc]]
    #NOVA
    enable_service n-cell
```

I learned to enable the service by looking at [this commit](https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack/commit/71119b47a0e3fb86b349732a1777be8c83d2e6c2)

The commit message states:

> "When cellsv1 is used (n-cell is enabled) skip calling
>   cells_v2 simple_cell_setup, which will never have hosts
>   at the top level and which will always fail."

Now I'm stuck trying to resolve version conflicts with Cliff and hacking python packages. I hope this helps.

Comment: What else did you find Trevor, curiously I hit this same issue this morning.

Comment: Hey amrith, I'm new to answering questions on stackoverflow and I missed the notifications for this but now I found them! Looks like it solved the problem, anyways, this is most likely no longer a problem.

Comment: I added placement-api to the enabled_services list in local.conf and that worked for me. But its not working any longer on subsequent unstack and stack. Any reason?

Comment: You can try RECLONE=True, to update your repositories. You can try ./clean.sh to remove some extra configuration steps that weren't removed in ./unstack.sh (like mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Trevor - your solution helped to resolve the exact problem I faced. After I did as you have stated, my dev stack is up!

```
....
+./stack.sh:main:1412                      set +o xtrace

=========================
DevStack Component Timing
=========================
Total runtime         590

run_process            61
test_with_retry         2
apt-get-update          3
pip_install            66
restart_apache_server   8
wait_for_service       10
apt-get                27
=========================



This is your host IP address: 192.168.1.103
This is your host IPv6 address: ::1
Horizon is now available at http://192.168.1.103/dashboard
Keystone is serving at http://192.168.1.103/identity/
The default users are: admin and demo
The password: secret
2016-12-28 04:23:06.124 | WARNING: 
2016-12-28 04:23:06.124 | Using lib/neutron-legacy is deprecated, and it will be removed in the future
2016-12-28 04:23:06.124 | stack.sh completed in 590 seconds.
```

NOTE: I couldn't comment to your answer so I'm posting as an answer. HTH.
Installed devStack on Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Welcome to SO, if you find a correct solution, please mark it as correct! thanks